# Hide only the parent of this element when empty

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide a parent of an element if it's empty. I'm making a list of working hours. I got 7 fields for each day. But if you want to make an item with Monday till Friday I want to make the others 4 fields disabled.

at the moment I got this:

```
  function isEmpty( el ){
      return !$.trim(el.html())
  }

  if (isEmpty($('p .spanItem')) && isEmpty($('p .spanEnd'))) {
       $(".spanItem").parent().hide();
```

This makes the parent disabled but also disables the other parents which mean it doesn't show a list at all.

Also if the first element has content in it then the function will be ignored even though other elements are empty.

```
<p><?php echo $row['day_one']?>:         <span class="spanItem"><?php echo $row['day_one_starttime'] ?></span>          <span class="spanEnd"><?php echo $row['day_one_closing'] ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['day_two']?>:         <span class="spanItem"><?php echo $row['day_two_starttime'] ?></span>          <span class="spanEnd"><?php echo $row['day_two_closing'] ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['day_three']?>:       <span class="spanItem"><?php echo $row['day_three_starttime'] ?></span>        <span class="spanEnd"><?php echo $row['day_three_closing'] ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['day_four']?>:        <span class="spanItem"><?php echo $row['day_four_starttime'] ?></span>         <span class="spanEnd"><?php echo $row['day_four_closing'] ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['day_five']?>:        <span class="spanItem"><?php echo $row['day_five_starttime'] ?></span>         <span class="spanEnd"><?php echo $row['day_five_closing'] ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['day_six']?>:         <span class="spanItem"><?php echo $row['day_six_starttime'] ?></span>      <span class="spanEnd"><?php echo $row['day_six_closing'] ?></p>
<p><?php echo $row['day_seven']?>:       <span class="spanItem"><?php echo $row['day_seven_starttime'] ?></span>        <span class="spanEnd"><?php echo $row['day_seven_closing'] ?></p>
```

Seen all lot of examples with $(this) but they were all click functions. I tried to work with $(this) but it didn't work.

I can add a class to each

and call that class but that makes my code unnecessary long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're checking all the `.spanItem` elements at once. You need to instead loop through them and check each one individually:

```js
$('p').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).find('.spanItem').text().trim() + $(this).find('.spanEnd').text().trim();
  $(this).toggle(text.trim() !== '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Day one:
  <span class="spanItem">Day one start</span> 
  <span class="spanEnd">Day one closing</span>
</p>
<p>
  Day two: <!-- this will be hidden --> 
  <span class="spanItem"></span> 
  <span class="spanEnd"></span>
</p>
<p>
  Day three:
  <span class="spanItem"></span> 
  <span class="spanEnd">Day three closing</span>
</p>
<p>
  Day four: <!-- this will be hidden --> 
  <span class="spanItem"></span> 
  <span class="spanEnd"></span>
</p>
<p>
  Day five:
  <span class="spanItem">Day five start</span> 
  <span class="spanEnd"></span>
</p>
<p>
  Day six: <!-- this will be hidden --> 
  <span class="spanItem"></span> 
  <span class="spanEnd"></span>
</p>
<p>
  Day seven:
  <span class="spanItem">Day seven start</span> 
  <span class="spanEnd">Day seven closing</span>
</p>
```

I simplified the logic by checking if `text()` is empty, and using `toggle()` to hide/show the parent as required. Also note that you're missing some `</span>` tags in your HTML.

Comment: Much appreciated. Made a small adjustment because it toggled other p elements to none outside the list. But it is working perfectly now.

Comment: No problem, glad to help